# how can i populate a field with id while saving but id is not existing yet

Tags: django

I am building a helpdesk system and I would like to have a automated ticket designation based on the length of the ID.
Example:
The ID of a ticket is 47 so I would like to have a 5 Integer long designation -> #00047 or if ID 2021 designation should be #02021

my relevant code:
My Model:

```
class Ticket(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True)
    designation = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True, null=True)
```

I tried do populate the fields with a for loop in my views.py

```
 def Index(request):
    ticket = Ticket.objects.all()
    for t in ticket:
      id = len(str(t.id))
      if id == 1:
        t.designation = "#" + str("0000") + str(t.id)
      elif id == 2:
        t.designation = "#" + str("000") + str(t.id)
      elif id == 3:
        t.designation = "#" + str("00") + str(t.id)
      elif id == 4:
        t.designation = "#" + str("0") + str(t.id)
      else:
        t.designation = "#" + str(t.id)
    context = {'ticket':ticket}
    return render(request, 'ticketsystem/index.html', context)
```

and the output was correct, but I would like to have the population while creating the object

i tried the following, by adding it to my Ticket model:

```
class Ticket(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True)
    designation = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True, null=True)

    def save(self):
        id = len(str(id))
        if id == 1:
            designation = "#" + str("0000") + str(id)
        elif id == 2:
            designation = "#" + str("000") + str(id)
        elif id == 3:
            designation = "#" + str("00") + str(id)
        elif id == 4:
            designation = "#" + str("0") + str(id)
        else:
            designation = "#" + str(id)
        super().save()
```

but following error comes up:

local variable 'id' referenced before assignment

Answer (score 1):

You need to run the `super` call before everything else, otherwise, your object won't be in the DB.

```py
class Ticket(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True)
    designation = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True, null=True)

    def save(self):
        if not self.pk:
            super().save()

        str_id = str(self.pk)
        if str_id == 1:
            self.designation = "#0000{}".format(str_id)
        elif str_id == 2:
            self.designation = "#000{}".format(str_id)
        elif str_id == 3:
            self.designation = "#00{}".format(str_id)
        elif str_id == 4:
            self.designation = "#0{}".format(str_id)
        else:
            self.designation = "#{}".format(str_id)

        return self.save()
```

Comment: doesnt seem to work with forms? error: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'id'

Comment: or simplify a bit with `self.designation = "#{0:05.0f}".format(self.id)` or `self.designation = f"#{self.id:05.0f}"` instead of the ifs.

Answer (score 0):

You've not overwritten the `id` field so it is going to be an integer and you want to let Django handle the autoincrement etc.

You would be better off (in my opinion) simply adding a new field which takes the id and converts it to a string

```
class Ticket(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True)

    @property
    def ticketkennung(self):
        this_id = str(self.id)
        if len(this_id) = 1 : str_id = '0000' + this_id
        etc ...
        return this_id
```

OR

```
class Ticket(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True)
    designation = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True, null=True)

    def save(self):
        this_id = len(str(self.id))
        if id == 1: self.designation = "#" + str("0000") + str(id)
        etc
        super().save(*args, **kwargs)
```

Comment: the field "ticketkennung" (which should be translated into designation) is the field i want to use for that,How would that function even "touch" the designation field?

Comment: I've edited answer as I think you want it.  This means it isn't saved into the database but is calculated all the time - I'm about to make another edit to show a different approach

Comment: okay thanks, i wait for it. the approach with always calculating uses unnecessery performance .. with this approch i could've used my forloop everytime ^^

Comment: on your property if using 3.6 or above, you can use f strings. `return f"#{self.id:05.0f}"`

Comment: the 2nd approach would be amazing, but at the time the save func is called, there is id not existing yet so it saves as "#0None"

Comment: then put `super().save(*args, **kwargs)` as first line in save method